# linux tc command don't affect download speed

Tags: networking, 20.04, downloads, download-speed, traffic

I want to set up upload and download restrictions using the 'tc' command on Linux. I am working on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.

By applying the following commands, the upload bandwidth is limited to ~1 Mbit, while the download bandwidth isn't affected

I am quite new to tc and would appreciate help with this.

```
sudo tc qdisc add dev ens33 root handle 1: htb default 12
sudo tc class add dev ens33 parent 1:1 classid 1:12 htb rate 1Mbit
sudo tc filter add dev ens33 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip dst 10.0.0.162 flowid 1:12
sudo tc class add dev ens33 parent 1:1 classid 1:13 htb rate 1Mbit
sudo tc filter add dev ens33 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip src 10.0.0.162 flowid 1:13
```

Is it possible that download restrictions only work on specific Linux versions?

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who has the same problem, i figured out how to limit download speed:

```
tc qdisc add dev ens33 handle ffff: ingress
tc filter add dev ens33 protocol ip parent ffff: prio 50 u32 match ip src 0.0.0.0/0 police rate 128kbit burst 15k drop flowid :1
```

You can delete this filter with this command:

```
tc filter del dev ens33 parent ffff: prio 50
```

I got the answer from the following forum:
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/limit-bandwidth-of-a-network-interface-tc-and-iptables-doesn%27t-work-837259/